# Arrastrar Importes SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estoy preparando una consulta *SQL* para un listado de rotación de *stock*. Básicamente lo que necesito es que los movimientos de entrada y salida de *stock* vayan acumulándose en cada registro teniendo el total de movimientos en una fecha en concreto.

```
WITH RES1 AS
(
    SELECT
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ROT.Articulo, ROT.Almacen ORDER BY ROT.FechaMovimiento) AS Id, 
           ROT.Articulo, ROT.Almacen, ROT.FechaMovimiento, ROT.Cantidad
    FROM
           LINEAS_ROTACION ROT
)
SELECT 
    RES1.AR_Ref, RES1.Almacen, RES1.FechaMovimiento, 
    SUM(RES1.Cantidad) OVER(PARTITION BY RES1.Articulo, RES1.Almacen ORDER BY RES.Id) AS MovimientoEnFecha
FROM RES1;
```

La tabla `LINEAS_ROTACION` simplemente contiene registros de movimientos (`Articulo`, `Almacen`, `Cantidad` en positivo o negativo y `Fecha` del movimiento).

El problema es que al ejecutarla obtengo el error `Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de Order` en la parte del `ORDER BY RES.Id`.

¿Se me está escapando algo?

¿Puede ser una limitación de *SQL Server 2008* para el `SUM OVER PARTITION`?

Tampoco sé si la consulta haría lo que quiero pero si no ordeno la suma de movimientos no será correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta tiene 2 errores:

- El CTE `RES1` no tiene una columna llamada `AR_Ref`, que luego intentas utilizar en el `select` final.
- En el `select` final haces referencia a `RES.Id`, pero no hay ningún objeto llamado `RES`, probablemente quieres hacer referencia a `RES1.Id`.

Corrigiendo esos dos detalles, no veo razón para que tu consulta no corra.

```
WITH 
RES1 AS
(
select   ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ROT.Articulo, ROT.Almacen order by ROT.FechaMovimiento) AS Id
       , ROT.Articulo
       , ROT.Almacen
       , ROT.FechaMovimiento
       , ROT.Cantidad
       , ROT.AR_Ref
  from LINEAS_ROTACION ROT
)
select   RES1.Articulo
       , RES1.Almacen
       , RES1.AR_Ref
       , RES1.FechaMovimiento
       , SUM(RES1.Cantidad) OVER(partition by RES1.Articulo, RES1.Almacen order by RES1.Id) as Saldo
  from RES1
 order by RES1.Articulo, RES1.Almacen, RES1.Id
```

Dicho esto, no veo razón para la existencia del CTE `RES1`, al menos con el ejemplo que nos das. El cálculo se podría hacer directamente haciendo la consulta sobre `LINEAS_ROTACION`, pues la columna `Id` no forma parte de los resultados y en el `sum` podemos hacer el `order by` directamente sobre `FechaMovimiento`, algo como:

```
select   rot.Articulo
       , rot.Almacen
       , rot.AR_Ref
       , rot.FechaMovimiento
       , SUM(rot.Cantidad) OVER(partition by rot.Articulo, rot.Almacen order by rot.FechaMovimiento) as Saldo
  from LINEAS_ROTACION rot
 order by rot.Articulo, rot.Almacen, rot.FechaMovimiento
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que SQL Server 2008 no soporta el `SUM() OVER( ORDER BY)` por lo que hay que utilizar técnicas antiguas. Se puede realizar con `joins triangulares` o `cursores`

LA primera opción es muy lenta por toda la cantidad de información que requiere. La fórmula básica es `(X2+X)/2 + X` donde X es el número de filas devueltas. Es decir, si tu resultado son 10 filas, tendrás que leer 65 filas, pero si son 100, serán 5150 y así creciendo exponencialmente.

Los segundos son una opción más eficiente pero pueden ser lentos por calcular una fila a la vez.

Finalmente, tenemos una opción más oscura pero muy eficiente y es hacer un UPDATE especial. Esta opción requiere varias reglas y debe ser probada correctamente. [Aquí](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten) hay un artículo en inglés especificando todo esto.

Aquí dejo un resúmen en forma de código documentado que se aplica a tu ejemplo. Los tipos de datos son asumidos pero deben cambiarse según tu tabla.

```
--Definir la tabla para el resultado con un índice clustered en el orden correcto.
CREATE TABLE #LINEAS_ROTACION(
    Id                  bigint,
    Articulo            int, 
    Almacen             int, 
    FechaMovimiento     datetime, 
    Cantidad            decimal(18,2),
    MovimientoEnFecha   decimal(18,2)
);
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_TempLINEAS_ROTACION ON #LINEAS_ROTACION(Id);

--Insertar los datos a la tabla temporal definiendo el orden
INSERT INTO #LINEAS_ROTACION( Id, Articulo, Almacen, FechaMovimiento, Cantidad)
SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ROT.Articulo, ROT.Almacen ORDER BY ROT.FechaMovimiento) AS Id, 
        ROT.Articulo, ROT.Almacen, ROT.FechaMovimiento, ROT.Cantidad
FROM
        LINEAS_ROTACION ROT

-- Definir las variables necesarias para el UPDATE
DECLARE @Articulo   int,
        @Almacen    int,
        @MovimientoEnFecha decimal(18,2);

-- Llenar la columna MovimientoEnFecha reiniciando en cada cambio de articulo o almacen. 
-- El orden está definido por el índice clustered
UPDATE LR
    SET @MovimientoEnFecha = MovimientoEnFecha = CASE WHEN @Articulo = Articulo AND @Almacen = Almacen THEN @MovimientoEnFecha ELSE 0 END + MovimientoEnFecha,
        @Articulo = Articulo,
        @Almacen = Almacen
FROM #LINEAS_ROTACION LR WITH (TABLOCKX) --En teoría no es necesario pero evita que otros usuarios afecten la tabla
OPTION (MAXDOP 1); --Previene el paralelismo que puede hacer saltar filas

SELECT 
    Articulo,
    Almacen, 
    FechaMovimiento, 
    MovimientoEnFecha
FROM #LINEAS_ROTACION;
```

## Las Reglas

1. El índice clustered debe estar presente en el orden correcto.
2. Se debe evitar el paralelismo
3. No trabajes con tablas particionadas
4. Usa el Hint TABLOCKX
5. No usar JOINS
6. Necesitas tener una columna “ancla” (en este caso articulo y almacen sirven como tal)
7. No usar ORDER BY (no sirve de nada)
8. No usar Hints de índices para intentar forzar el órden
9. Hazlo bien, sí detectas que no funciona, ve paso a paso hasta hacerlo funcionar
10. ¡PRUEBA, PRUEBA y PRUEBA de nuevo!